# Avoid deadlock from for update

Tags: oracle, cursor, deadlock, commit, database-deadlocks

How to release the row level lock of another session to avoid dead lock from **for update**?
I have a table

[image]

Here is the code,

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT id
      FROM tasks;
ls_id NUMBER;
vaf varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
OPEN c1;
LOOP
    FETCH c1
        INTO ls_id;
  vaf := 'select * from  tasks where id =''' || ls_id ||
           ''' for update of id';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vaf;
    UPDATE tasks
       SET status = 'B'
     WHERE id = ls_id;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c1;
commit;
END;
```

if i first run the **for update** the table **tasks** where id=4 row in one session, and then run the above block in another session in plsql developer ide test window and executing line by line.The loops goes on and getting deadlock at id=4.Here i'm committing after the loop so there will be no update will be in id=1,2 and 3. If i put commit after the update statement it will update the record up to id =3 and getting deadlock at id=4. Yes, putting commit inside the loop is not a good idea.

So to avoid the deadlock, i have used skip locked.

```
SELECT id FROM tasks FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

This one solves the deadlock at id=4 but instead skip the locked record id=4 and updated remaining record.

killing the session is not permitted. Is any other possible way to updated the locked record?
Since i'm running a scheduler which is updating the important trans. So i don't need to avoid or skip the locked record and as well as scheduler not getting dead lock. Is it possible?

Comment: Is a column you're updating also a foreign key column? If so, is that column indexed? If not, try to create an index on it. Depending on your database version, lock happens on unindexed foreign columns. Maybe it'll help & won't cost much to try.

Comment: *"Is any other possible way to updated the locked record?"* No. The other session has the lock and you can't touch the record until that session releases it. If you provide a little more detail about the business logic you're trying to implement we might be able to give some advice. As it is, all we can do is look at your code in a bemused fashion.

Answer (score 1):

So you are doing an update on the tasks table, setting the value of task.status on **every row** to 'B'. The problem with your code is that you select all rows from tasks to drive your processing regardless of if they are locked are not, then try to lock each individual row as you process it in the loop. Logically, what you seem to be wanting to do is update all the rows in tasks every time this is run. The only reliable way to do this then is to lock all the rows from the start.

The logic of your code can be simplified down to:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT *
      FROM tasks
      FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
   row_locked EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(row_locked, -54);
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   UPDATE tasks SET status = 'B';
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN row_locked THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Table is busy' );
      ROLLBACK;
      IF c1%ISOPEN THEN CLOSE c1;
END;
```

If however, you want to execute this code in different sessions potentially at the same time, it will give rise to blocking locks potentially deadlocks.

Perhaps adding a `WHERE status != 'B'` condition might reduce the chances.

If not, consider using AQ to serialise the updates requests which will help with ordering the process queue. This is generic advice, since we would need more details about the full usages of this table to give specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED**

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT id
      FROM tasks;
ls_id NUMBER;
vaf varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
OPEN c1;
LOOP
    FETCH c1
        INTO ls_id;
  vaf := 'select * from  tasks where id =''' || ls_id ||
           ''' for update of id skip locked';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vaf;
    UPDATE tasks
       SET status = 'B'
     WHERE id = ls_id;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c1;
commit;
END;
```

If you want to avoid the deadlock, try to use the clause skip locked. Also bear in mind that If you specify SKIP LOCKED and the table is locked in exclusive mode by another session, then the database will not return the results of the SELECT statement until the lock on the table is released.

Comment: Thanks for the response sir. after i run the block its getting deadlock at id=4. `vaf := 'select * from  tasks where id =''' || ls_id || ''' for update of id skip locked';`

Comment: Hi. The deadlock is produced on ID=4 where you run the process in another session right ?? What do you want to use select for update ??

Comment: if you explain me what are you trying to achieve, perhaps I might be able to provide you a better idea than using select for update.